# Exclude process memory region from kernel and heap usage

Tags: c, gcc, linker, linux-kernel, shared-memory

I'm trying to implement the solution suggested in this question

[Is it possible to store pointers in shared memory without using offsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489908/is-it-possible-to-store-pointers-in-shared-memory-without-using-offsets/2672075#comment23557597_2672075)

The proposed solution involves specifying a memory to 0x20000000000 to

```
void *shmat(int shmid, const void *shmaddr, int shmflg);
```

The problem is that this mapping may fail because its in use already. I want to know if this can be avoided by making sure 0x20000000000 is not used by

1. kernel
2. linker (i.e. .text/.bss etc. regions of executable)

This is what I found so far which isn't very satisfactory

[How do I pass virtual address to shmat() function in a guaranteed way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188091/how-do-i-pass-virtual-address-to-shmat-function-in-a-guaranteed-way)

Comment: If you do the `shmat(id, NULL, flag);` and follow with a `fork();`, then the parent and child already share memory at the same addresses.  If your processes are in completely different address spaces, then your question is wrong.  You want to find a unique pointer/shmat for two (or more) processes.  You can't pick some address generically. `cat /proc/pid/maps` has this info.  Typically the memory split is 3G/1G on 32-bit, so kernel only uses high memory.

Comment: @artlessnoise - I agree fork could work, but its messy. I'm not sure I follow "If your processes are in completely different address spaces, then your question is wrong". Could you explain? I was hoping there would be a way to mark a section of virtual address space to be unavailable to - loader/linker, kernel and heap. Is there some way?

Comment: You would have to do this for *every executable* that uses this mechanism.  The kernel can map shared libraries, like `libc`, to any location that is free.  You could create a linker script for all of the *executables* and reserve some common low memory location.  I was saying you can not do this if you are writing a library; you need to have control over the address space.  A library could search through `/proc/pid/maps` to find a free region in all processes and try to use that.  By using a *linker script*, you can reserve some area if you are building all of the main executeables.

Comment: I do have access to the executable(s) using this mechanism. Would you be able to post a startup example of such a script/program?

Comment: Try `ld --verbose` with your standard linker line.  This should dump the linker scripts in use. Lots of on-line resource: [sections when linking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508290/how-to-specify-base-addresses-for-sections-when-linking-or-alternatively-how-to), [Elf object format](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1060), etc.

Comment: Fair enough, I can try it out. My reservation is that if the approach is valid i.e. if one reserves memory using the linker script, will shmat on that location work without fail?

Comment: The question would be will `ld.so` reserve this memory.  I tried `man ld.so` and I don't see anyway to reserve memory.  If you map a section to a linker script, then the `ld.so` will allocate it via `mmap` or something else.  When this happens, `shmat` will fail.  You could **statically link** and then reserve a section as `NOLOAD` and I think that would work.  Somehow, you will have to free/release a section with `ld.so`, maybe with `munmap`, but that is a guess.